# Chance of Ravana to win the war against Ram

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, vibhishana

If Vibhishan is not in the Rama's side . What is a chance of Ravan to defeat Ram in the war. As we can see that Vibhishan has pretty good impact in the war. like;

1) He told Ram about real Makarakhsha's(*Son of Khar*) identity among all clones or fake Makarakhsha.

2) When Laxman(*Ram's Brother*) had severe injury cause by the dagger of Indrajeet(*Son of Ravana*) He gave the idea to consult *Raj-Vaidhya*(*Royal Physician*) of Lanka (I think his name is Shushurna) which gave the idea of *Mrit-Sanjeevani* (*Some kind of shrub which has property to give life to person who is dead or about to die*) which eventually save Laxman.

3) He told Ram about Indrajeet worshipping Nikumbla to get Chariot and If he ride that Chariot, He will be Invincible and hence Laxman with the help of *vanaras* failed Yagna in between.

4) He told Ram that Ravan has amrit in his belly that is why he cant be kill until you dry amrit from his belly.

This is very important information provided by Vibhishan to Ram. *Is Vibishan is actually a cause for defeat of Ravana ?*

**Note : All information is gathered from Ramanand Sagar's Television Series Ramayan**

Comment: First of all, There were no fake Makarakshas. Second of all, There was no pot of amrit in the belly of Ravana. This is an addition in later edition of Ramayana. Third of all, Answers to this question would be purely based on speculation rather than expertise. So, this question might get closed.

Comment: Who ever takes birth, he need to die one day. Ravana was not exception of it. Everyone's reason, time and place of death is pre-planned. Ravana's death was also pre planned by Brahma. Vibhishan was just an medium like Rama for the death of Ravana. Yes, Rama was also just an medium. Actually Ravana (and everyone else also) was killed by his own karma. Everyone's death is totally based of their karma. Lord will create excuses or medium for your death in may different forms or ways like decease, accident etc.

Comment: Did the supreme lord Vishnu _have_ to be born as a human to kill a mere demon who had been terrorized by multiple other humans and monkeys of his time, or did he do so to ensure that the boon given by Brahma would not be in vain? Think about it. By a mere thought of Vishnu, Ravana could have ceased to exist. But the supreme lord wished to keep everything in place while effecting the end of the evil asura.

Comment: Chance of ravana to win against rama? Nil. As for others helping Rama in his mission, I heard a beautiful analogy. When someone is visiting tirupati, it is our tendency to give them some offering (usually money) to place in the hundi on our behalf. They collect all the monies and go to tirupati. This does not mean that they are able to go only because we gave them money. They would have gone regardless but we were given an opportunity to make an offering.

Comment: Isn't it possible that Rama & Vishnu were different? That they were not the same person?